# how to display a byte array as image

Tags: android, bitmap, arrays, converters, pixel

**I converted image into  grayscale then read the pixels like this**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < image.getHeight(); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < image.getWidth(); j++)
                {
                      pixels[k]=(byte) (image.getPixel(j, i));
                      pixels2[k]=unsignedToBytes(pixels[k]);
                      k++;
                }
            }
```

**And performed edge detection now getting positive byte array so how should i again display it as image tried this one but not getting result**

```
imageView1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(edgeImage1, 0, edgeImage1.length));
```

**please help us....**

```
public int edgedetection6(int[][] oimage,int tblock) 
{
    ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView1);
    int edgeImage[][]=new int[42][42];
    byte edgeImage1[]=new byte[42*42];
    int n=0;
    //int s[][]={{-1,-1,-1},{-1,8,-1},{-1,-1,-1}};
    long R=0;
    for(int i=0;i<42;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<42;j++)
        {
            if(i==0 || j==0 || i==41 || j==41 )
            edgeImage[i][j]=0;
            else
                edgeImage[i][j]=oimage[i-1][j-1];

        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<40;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<40;j++)
        {
            R=8*edgeImage[i+1][j+1]-(edgeImage[i][j]+edgeImage[i][j+1]+edgeImage[i][j+2]+edgeImage[i+1][j]+edgeImage[i+1][j+2]+edgeImage[i+2][j]+edgeImage[i+2][j+1]+edgeImage[i+2][j+2]);
            if(R>0)
                edgeImage[i+1][j+1]=1;
            else
                edgeImage[i+1][j+1]=0;
            edgeImage1[n]=(byte)edgeImage[i][j];
            n++;
        }

    }

               ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView1);
           imageView1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(edgeImage1, 0, edgeImage.length));
```

}

Comment: What is the output?? Is it showing exception or is it displaying Black image in `imageView1`

Comment: displaying black image in imageView1

Comment: I think you have messed up at `edgeImage1`. Check the logic, there might be some issue.

Comment: Added edge detection function here 40*40 block of image is passed and added 2 extra columns n 2 extra rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing extra row and column for frame like pattern is OK...

But I think edge detection code you posted is dicey..

Let me give you sample for edge detection for your ref..

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class ImageProcessingActivity extends Activity {

 final static int KERNAL_WIDTH = 3;
 final static int KERNAL_HEIGHT = 3;

 int[][] kernal ={
   {0, -1, 0},
   {-1, 4, -1},
   {0, -1, 0}
 };

 ImageView imageSource, imageAfter;
 Bitmap bitmap_Source;
 ProgressBar progressBar;

 private Handler handler;
 Bitmap afterProcess;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        imageSource = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageSource);
        imageAfter = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageAfter);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        bitmap_Source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        handler = new Handler();
        StratBackgroundProcess();
    }

    private void StratBackgroundProcess(){

     Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){

   @Override
   public void run() {
    afterProcess = processingBitmap(bitmap_Source, kernal);

    handler.post(new Runnable(){

     @Override
     public void run() {
      progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      imageAfter.setImageBitmap(afterProcess);
     }

    });
   }
     };
     new Thread(runnable).start();
    }

    private Bitmap processingBitmap(Bitmap src, int[][] knl){
     Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(
       src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), src.getConfig());

     int bmWidth = src.getWidth();
     int bmHeight = src.getHeight();
     int bmWidth_MINUS_2 = bmWidth - 2;
     int bmHeight_MINUS_2 = bmHeight - 2;

     for(int i = 1; i <= bmWidth_MINUS_2; i++){
      for(int j = 1; j <= bmHeight_MINUS_2; j++){

       //get the surround 3*3 pixel of current src[i][j] into a matrix subSrc[][]
       int[][] subSrc = new int[KERNAL_WIDTH][KERNAL_HEIGHT];
       for(int k = 0; k < KERNAL_WIDTH; k++){
        for(int l = 0; l < KERNAL_HEIGHT; l++){
         subSrc[k][l] = src.getPixel(i-1+k, j-1+l);
        }
       }

       //subSum = subSrc[][] * knl[][]
       int subSumA = 0;
       int subSumR = 0;
       int subSumG = 0;
       int subSumB = 0;

       for(int k = 0; k < KERNAL_WIDTH; k++){
        for(int l = 0; l < KERNAL_HEIGHT; l++){
         subSumR += Color.red(subSrc[k][l]) * knl[k][l];
         subSumG += Color.green(subSrc[k][l]) * knl[k][l];
         subSumB += Color.blue(subSrc[k][l]) * knl[k][l];
        }
       }

       subSumA = Color.alpha(src.getPixel(i, j));

       if(subSumR <0){
        subSumR = 0;
       }else if(subSumR > 255){
        subSumR = 255;
       }

       if(subSumG <0){
        subSumG = 0;
       }else if(subSumG > 255){
        subSumG = 255;
       }

       if(subSumB <0){
        subSumB = 0;
       }else if(subSumB > 255){
        subSumB = 255;
       }

       dest.setPixel(i, j, Color.argb(
         subSumA,
         subSumR,
         subSumG,
         subSumB));
      }
     }

     return dest;
    }

}
```

and in main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical" >
         <TextView
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Original" />
      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageSource"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
      <TextView
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Result" />
      <FrameLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/imageAfter"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
          <ProgressBar
              android:id="@+id/progressBar"
              style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      </FrameLayout>

     </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I think that's a complete code.. you will get an idea for your project..

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanku so much... but i have gray scale image Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 format

Comment: Happy to know that it solved your problem. Now, mark this answer as correct for others to benefit...

Comment: And one more problem sir how to set white pixels as 1 and black as 0.... its displaying 0 and non negative values after reading pixel values...